# How to use JS-Cookie in an if statement

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies, js-cookie

I'm looking to use cookies to disable a button after one press using Js-Cookie for a quiz

```
start_btn.onclick = ()=>{
    info_box.classList.add("activeInfo"); 
}
```

I'm not sure whether I should reference the button or edit its function?

so say I was to do

```
 start_btn.onclick = ()=>{
    info_box.classList.add("activeInfo"); 
    Cookies.set('completedquiz')
}
```

how would i then search for the cookie before loading the rest of the quiz
I've looked a lot on YouTube and haven't found much along with the page itself https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie
but couldn't find what I was looking for

I now have

```
if( Cookies.get('completedquiz') ) {
start_btn.onclick = ()=>{
    returnfalse 
}
} else {
start_btn.onclick = ()=>{
    info_box.classList.add("activeInfo"); 
    Cookies.set('completedquiz', { expires: 7 })
}
```

but it just does the else whether I have the cookie or not

Got it

```
if( Cookies.get('completedquiz') == 'true') {
start_btn.onclick = ()=>{
    return false 
}
} else {
start_btn.onclick = ()=>{
    info_box.classList.add("activeInfo"); 
    Cookies.set('completedquiz', 'true', { expires: 7 })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the answer would depend on how you're loading the rest of the quiz.

If you're loading it via Javascript you'd likely need to do the following:

```
if( Cookies.get('completedquiz') ) {
    // Don't load quiz
} else {
    // Load rest of quiz 
}
```

If you're loading the quiz via PHP you'd do the following:

```
if($_GET['completedquiz']) :
    // Don't load quiz
else :
    // Load rest of quiz
endif;
```

Reading the contents of the Cookie is covered in the documentation under **Basic Usage > Read**:
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Hope that helps!